# Chunked web service response

Tags: android

can you please provide me with an example on how to read a chuncked response from a web service in Android

thanks

**Edit:**
I'm try to call a soap web service, that replies to me with a base64 encoded string representing an image

here's the code:

```
String SOAP_ACTION = "service soap action";
         try {
            URL u = new URL("server url");
            URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
               connection.setDoInput(true);
               connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION);
               connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
               connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
String xmldata="soap request envelope";
//send the request
               OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();

                  Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

                  wout.write(xmldata);

                  wout.flush();

                  wout.close();

                  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));



                    String result;
                    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
                            //read response
                    while ((result=rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(result);
                    }
```

Comment: Show your code. How are you already doing it and what problems you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use more generalized classes, such as [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) and [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) to handle HTTP-interaction in a more higher level.

Comment: What you are getting? Response body with "chunk" spliters? Can you show it?

Comment: No I'm getting incomplete response body, the response is a soap response. something like this ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><LogoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><LogoResult><Image>iVBOR  and the closing tags are missing

Comment: Is DefaultHttpClient+HttpPost giving the same result?

Comment: I think you are already checked it thousand times, but... is your service returning a correct result? Can you emulate a call (using Fiddler or smth else) and get a valid response?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded a web service client app. tested the service, the response is correct, but when called from android app it returns an incomplete response

Answer (score 1):

## Preachy Answers:

1. You should really use a SOAP library rather than trying to re-invent the wheel: [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)
2. If possible use a REST service rather than SOAP since SOAP is not suited for mobile platforms: http://javatheelixir.blogspot.com/2009/12/soap-vs-rest-in-service-layer-for.html

## Practical Answer:

#### Problem:

- It seems you are only getting the first chunk of the response.

#### Possible solutions

1. Try write(int c) instead of write(String str). Then ignore \r and \n characters.
2. Use read() in a loop instead of readLine().

*Note to questioner:* Apologies for leaving in the Preachy answers. I am sure that you have considered those options. But it will help people who are able to use a SOAP library. If you have decided not to use a SOAP library for a specific reason please put it in the comments for the benifit of others.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to use the urlconnection class. You'll want to use the httpclient bundled with android like follows.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://something.com/something");
HttpResponse response = client.execute();

int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if(code == 200){
   InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

   //Now parse the xml coming back
   SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
   SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

   XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
   YourParser parser = new YourParser();

   xr.setContentHandler(parser);

   xr.parse(new InputSource(is));
}
```

You should simply need to create your xml parser to parse your objects.  Hope this helps.