# how to make login page with username and password using xml web service

Tags: android

how to make login page with username and password using xml web service..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [this](http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-use-http-connection-saxparser.html)

There is a very basic tutorial on this.

Also refer: [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android) Here you can get idea of using web services in Android.