# passing parameters to a soap webservice in android

Tags: android

I am working on an android application.I want to pass values to soap webservice.But i am not getting any response.Can anybody tell how should i pursue..

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: I think this is more of a Java and SOAP question than Android. Besides, you have to give more details.

Comment: Which details,,are u mentioning

Comment: At least the relevant code and perhaps the wsdl?

Comment: Btw, there is a nice discussion about Android and web services at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better to use ksoap2 service for android

Comment: can u give me a link or an example of ksoap webservice

Comment: Google can help you with that. It's the first hit.