# PHP REST API access by android application

Tags: android, web-services, rest

How to access webservice in android application. i am beginner in android app please help me step by step tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call web service with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial
http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/php-android

Comment: when i try to run it has following error \n has stopped unexpectedly.

Comment: hi  \n  now i call rest service? can you help me how to crate web application in android. how the native code interact with html pages and how to crate javascript in application i am using eclips ide.  thanks