# i want to retrive the data from site http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml

Tags: android, soap, weather

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call SOAP web service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-in-android)

i want to read the data http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml from this site related to weather using soap web service.... pls anyone help me

Comment: I think you need to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jeff Sharkey's android-sky project](http://code.google.com/p/android-sky/).  It uses http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml