# It's possible to use this webserver (http://dt106696/BpassPlus/General.asmx?WSDL) in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

i need to know if it's possible to use this webservice http://dt106696/BpassPlus/General.asmx?WSDL in Android application. It's possible?

This is a simple webservice with only one method and many types of arguments.
How is the best make it? using ksoap2 ?

thanks

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to resolve to anything for me -- dt106696 is, what?

Comment: And for general webservice + android questions there's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android, for example.

Comment: dt106696 is the name of machine in the network where webservice is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you specified is to a Windows network name that will not resolve for anyone who is not logically on the same Windows network as you.

Ksoap has libraries for Android, and unless you're doing something truly bizarre should be able to handle your needs: http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/