# how to call RESTful web service from android?

Tags: android, web-services, httprequest, httpresponse, restful-authentication

I have written REST web service in netbean IDE using jersey framework and java. For every request user need to provide username and password , I know the authentication is not good.
Using curl command like : 
curl -u username:password -X PUT http://localhsot:8080/user

Now I want to call REST web service from android class.What should I write? I am new to android. I have a android class which use DefaultHttpClient and CredentialUsernameAndPassword.
But when i run in eclipse, sometime I get runtime exception or sdk exception.

Do anyone give me sample code and suggestion?

thanks

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use basic authentication? if so: use this.

```
if (username != null && password != null) {
            client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(null, -1),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        }
```

or you can add those in a header as setHeader("Authentication", "Basic "+Base64EncodedString(username,pass);

What you are doing is using Proxy authentication. why?

this article may also be helpful somehow:

[link](http://androhacks.blogspot.com/2011/02/proxy-settings-in-android-mobiles-with.html)

also the -u stands for the ntlm authorization so maybe look into that too. there were some topics where it said it is not supported on android or something but i am sure if you need it you can make a workaround.