# Android Restful web service

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to call RESTful web service from android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046409/how-to-call-restful-web-service-from-android)

This is my web service link: "localhost:8080/data/resources/myapp.info/1".
How can i call it in java for an android application?

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046409/how-to-call-restful-web-service-from-android

Comment: What type of web service?  SOAP or RESTful?  What is "localhost" relative to - the Android device, or something on your desktop, etc.?

Comment: It's a restful web service, localhost... : it is the link of the service that is hosted locally on glassfish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had problems with localhost on the emulator. Try replacing localhost with the ipaddress of the machine you calling (using ifconfig). This worked for me yesterday.