# I am having a lot of trouble finding good information on how to call?

Tags: android

Android does not provide any sort of SOAP library. ... org.apache.http.

Comment: your question seem vague and ambigious, please edit your question so that it is much clearer and more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, thats true. SOAP are very difficult on android but might this can reach to your goal.

1) http://android.amberfog.com/?p=45

2) [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android)

3) http://www.anddev.org/calling_a_web_service_from_android-t348.html

for the calling purpose this (4) will help you.

4) http://xebee.xebia.in/2010/06/29/soap-web-service-call-in-android/