# Web services in Android

Tags: android, web-services

I want to use my own web service in my android application. Which will be the best way to do this?
  (I haven't written my web service yet)

I checked the other question also like [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-web-service-with-android) but they are too old.

Sorry, for repetitive question but I want to know if any new and better option is available.

Comment: The question itself may be a year old, but the answers are still perfectly valid! Have a look at REST, there are plenty of easy tutorials to follow :)

Comment: @James: Most of the answers tell about `SOAP` while rest mentioned that `REST` is more suitable. So got confused.

Comment: Read up on the debate between the two each has their own benefits....http://www.petefreitag.com/item/431.cfm  I've worked with ksoap2/SOAP on android and its really not bad or diffcult then again REST is also very simple.

Comment: Now I am thinking about `REST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to write a REST based web service. Use xml or json for data marshalling.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Now trying my hands on REST.