# Sending data from android app to server

Tags: android, sql-server

I'm new to android application development and I want to send data from an android app to MS SQL Sever.

Is it possible in android? If so, which methods can I use? If not, is there any alternative ways to send?

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much for reading.

Answer (score 2):

You may send data via WebService. Please take a look at [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/webservice-from-android.aspx) article and [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android) Thread.

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with @Walid and @adatapost that you need to create webservice for the same. And using webservice you can send and retrieve as per your requirement. So just try to search on the Android webservice call and webservice development articles. There are already many articles existed on the web currently.