# Insert data in MySQL through soap?

Tags: java, android, soap

We are working on an Android-app with a database connection (MySQL). Now we would like to insert data of a user in the database. Does anyone know safe methods to do this? Maybe to use php and soap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see this?

[How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android)

You could use PHP if you like or any other language that you find most fitting to create a SOAP web service (in the server/web tier). If you don't need to use SOAP and your data/web methods can be expressed as URLs/querystrings you can consider a RESTful web interface.