# How can i make simple call to network web service from android ?

Tags: android

I need to make some simple web service call from android. 
I know the server ip address - and i know what it the method that i need to call. 
The server is base on .net platform - and the method that i need to call will return to me simple string that will tell me what is the server web service version.

I don't know how to make this call.

Thanks for any help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what sort of webservice this is... a SOAP (XML) webservice would need some XML capabilities, easiest option is to use a library (see below for KSOAP2)... a REST webservice might work with pure HTTP (perhaps plus JSON)...

For some sample source code/walkthrough/library/doc regarding all mentioned options on how to call a webservice from Android see:

- http://naveenbalani.com/index.php/2011/01/invoke-webservices-from-android/
- [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android/303500#303500)
- http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Home
- http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/
- [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-in-http-request-with-android/3506039#3506039)
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Comment: The version 0.0.4 is out with tutorial:

http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/2012/04/16/Version+0.0.4+released

http://wiki.javaforum.hu/display/ANDROIDSOAP/Step+by+step+tutorial

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SOAPActivity extends Activity {
     private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";
        private final String URL = "http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertWeight.asmx";
        private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConvertWeight";
        private final String METHOD_NAME = "ConvertWeight";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SoapObject soapObject=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        String weight = "700";
        String fromUnit = "Kilograms";
        String toUnit = "Grams";

        PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
        weightProp.setName("Weight");
        weightProp.setValue(weight);
        weightProp.setType(double.class);
        soapObject.addProperty(weightProp);

        PropertyInfo fromProp =new PropertyInfo();
        fromProp.setName("FromUnit");
        fromProp.setValue(fromUnit);
        fromProp.setType(String.class);
        soapObject.addProperty(fromProp);

        PropertyInfo toProp =new PropertyInfo();
        toProp.setName("ToUnit");
        toProp.setValue(toUnit);
        toProp.setType(String.class);
        soapObject.addProperty(toProp);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("myApp", response.toString());

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(weight+" "+fromUnit+" equal "+response.toString()+ " "+toUnit);
            setContentView(tv);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
```

This is code for SOAP web service.