# How can I trigger a Java class present in a remote server from my Android phone?

Tags: android, web-services

I need to create an application which triggers a Java class *on a remote server*.
Can any one please help me out and give some clue about it?

Comment: what do you mean by `trigger`?

Comment: can u explain in detail?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for a web service.
[What is web service ?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)
[What is Apache Axis ?](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2002/jw-0125-axis.html)
[Simple tutorial to create Apache axis web service](http://www.softwareagility.gr/index.php?q=node/21)
[Calling web service from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android)