# android webservice call - issue

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am a newbie to Android platform.

I want to call a webservice from android java development enviornment. Am using axis technology to connect to a webservice in java development.

Can i use the same technology here in android development also.?

one more doubt am having is am using several jar files (like axis,commons-logging,commons-httpclient) in java dev enviornment for webservice call and its implementations.

Can i use these jar files in android java dev platform.?

Experts please give me a clear idea about all these..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your web service is SOAP you can use KSOAP2, it enables you communicate easily with SOAP web service. if your web service is REST you can then use classes like HttpClient, HttpGet and HttpPost that exist already on Android.

Comment: yea..am using a soap webservice and am using KSOAP2 and that enables me to access the webservice, issue is only when am passing the complex parameters like Objects and all(serialization issue). But if am passing a string then there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android).

It isn't possible to use Axis or some other framework as is with Android. You will have to recompile all jars with Android SDK in order to do so.