# android clients - java server implemenation

Tags: java, android, client

I am building a android clients - single server application, and want to use JSON objects for communication. Will have some simple database on the server. what would be a good scheme for server side implementation. Here are my options:

Socket programming - then can I still use HttpClient on the android client?
HttpServer - I heard it is not working well with android, and how do you do multithreading on server side?

any other recommendation would be helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is some interesting discussion over at this SO question that may provide some useful info: [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android)