# web service in android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services

I need to consume a web service from android/eclipse by soap method.

ie., i have to give an input and show an appropriate result from the web service as per the users input.How to do this?

**java class**

```
public class Demo_webserviceActivity extends Activity
{ 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
   private static String METHOD_NAME = "GetName";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetName";
    private static String URL = "http://122.248.240.105:234/Service1.asmx";

   Button btnFar;
   EditText txtFar,txtCel;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);

   txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFar);
   txtCel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCel);

   btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {

   public void onClick(View v)
   {
     //Initialize soap request + add parameters
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

     //Use this to add parameters
     request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

     //Declare the version of the SOAP request
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     envelope.dotNet = true;

     try 
     {
         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

         //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

         // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
         SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

         if(result != null)
         {
          //Get the first property and change the label text
           txtCel.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
         }
         else
         {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
       });
    } 
 }
```

**web method**

```
public class GetName 
{
public String GetName(String Fahrenheit){
    return(Fahrenheit);
}
}
```

**logcat**

```
06-12 17:40:00.322: W/InputManagerService(59): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44f60478 (uid=10040 pid=345)
 06-12 17:40:00.352: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(345): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
 06-12 17:40:07.292: D/AndroidRuntime(352): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-12 17:40:07.292: D/AndroidRuntime(352): CheckJNI is ON
06-12 17:40:07.477: D/AndroidRuntime(352): --- registering native functions ---
06-12 17:40:08.062: D/AndroidRuntime(352): Shutting down VM
06-12 17:40:08.062: D/dalvikvm(352): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-12 17:40:08.102: I/AndroidRuntime(352): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-12 17:40:08.502: D/AndroidRuntime(360): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-12 17:40:08.502: D/AndroidRuntime(360): CheckJNI is ON
06-12 17:40:08.633: D/AndroidRuntime(360): --- registering native functions ---
06-12 17:40:09.152: I/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.demo.webser/.Demo_webserviceActivity }
06-12 17:40:09.222: D/AndroidRuntime(360): Shutting down VM
06-12 17:40:09.222: D/dalvikvm(360): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-12 17:40:09.252: I/AndroidRuntime(360): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: [Let me do it for you ?](http://www.google.co.in/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+soap+web+service)

Comment: +1 Samir, and -1 @Rohith for Not searching out

Comment: Just a minute paresh i'll edit my question with what i have done so far

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call SOAP web service with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `SoapPrimitive results = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();` instead of `SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;` because your webservice is returning a `string` not `object`.

Comment: If i follow your answer. these lines showing error txtCel.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString()); what can i do

Comment: remove the getProperty(0) and try with result.toString()

Comment: It showing the same result as "Name not found"...i think may be problem on web method, was my web method source correct?

Comment: have you add the [WebMethod] just before the GetName() in webservice? and post ur logcat data.

Comment: yes i have added web method's source with logcat,please visit my question again...

Comment: i dont find "Name not found"... error in logcat? r u getting this error on 'txtCel' edittext?

Comment: "Name not found " is the answer right now i am getting on my edittext box...sorry its not an error.

Comment: The following web service is i am working with http://122.248.240.105:234/Service1.asmx   if you give "0001" as input on the method GetName you will get values as "Goundamani"..this is what i want

Comment: Thats y i am asking you may be problem on my web method's source

Comment: u r doing the wrong way with this webservice.change the following code request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString()); to request.addProperty("sName",txtFar.getText().toString()); because sName is parameter name GetName() receiving.

Comment: if my answer helped you, you should accept it so that other ppl will find it easily

Comment: surely..surely..sorry i forgotten that to do,due program ran

Comment: http://122.248.240.105:234/Service1.asmx?op=GetName look here parameter name is sName and in android u have to pass the same parameter as u write in webservice method.

Comment: Now i hope u understood this concept of android webservice call.

Comment: can u help to answer this question ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903238/how-to-parse-soap-response-when-child-tags-have-different-name-and-no-of-tag-are

Answer (score 1):

You are going in right direction i.e The code you are written in android is right.Just  make sure that **soap action , Method , URl and namespace** you are written is right.
If you have any doubts regarding this or any other doubts you can write me.

Here basic android tutorial to access web service in android[basic ksoap android tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html)

and for creating webservice in java use this Tutorial [How to create java based web service](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html)

Comment: The code you are given is write.Just make sure you Deploy that service correctly.Please follow the link I given in my answer to check the web service.And I already created web service using that link and its working.If still you have problem then write me.