# how to set parameters of webmethod in android

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, ksoap

I had created webservice using `jaxws` in `myeclipse5.1.1GA` and I can call this webservice method in `eclipse indigo64 bit`.
Problem is that when I can set parameters of webmethod which is in webservice 
using soap object's `setparameter()` method but it is not set in webservice's webmethod.

how to set parameter:

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {
    private String METHOD_NAME="";
    private String NAMESPACE="http://ws.easyway3e.com/";
    private String SOAP_ACTION="";
    private static final String URL="http://10.0.2.2:8080/WebService/DBConn?wsdl";
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
    System.out.println("Call-1 -----"+params[0]+","+params[1]+",
                       "+params[2]+","+params[3]);
    METHOD_NAME="openConnection";               
    SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty(DRIVERNAME);
    request.addProperty("d_Name",params[0]);
    request.addProperty("c_String",params[1]);
    request.addProperty("u_Name",params[2]);
    request.addProperty("pass",params[3]);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope
                                         (SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    System.out.println(envelope.bodyOut.toString());
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTranportSE=new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTranportSE.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" 
                                           encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    try {
        SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
        androidHttpTranportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        System.out.println(" Connection is =>"+resultsRequestSOAP.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
    Object result = null;
    try { result = envelope.getResponse(); } 
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your own question.You have put

`request.addProperty("d_Name",params[0]);`

and this is correct way to add parameter to SOAP webservice.

You can also refer the following links to clear your concept about webservice all in android.

[web service in android/eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995620/web-service-in-android-eclipse/10995857#10995857)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/index.html

Comment: i khown how to set parameter in webmethod using ksoap2 but i can not set into webservice's method when i can call it.

Comment: is it any problem to create webservice in jax-ws and to call it using ksoap2 in android

Comment: if you are using jax-ws why are you using  envelope.dotNet=true; in your code.