# How to create wsdl file in java

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl

i am new to Android and I would like to create a mobile application like web service concepts actually Java EE Web dynamic application using Struts frame work and Apache Tomcat so give the ideas how to create web service.

Answer (score 2):

open you dynamic web  in you web right click on your java file where you create all services, second last option is web services -> create web service.
after create web services test it.

Testing WSDL:-

WebContent -> wsdl -> service.wsdl-> right click -> web services -> test web services with services explorer

Answer (score 1):

When you create web service with Apache Axis it will automatically generate WSDL file for the web service. If you want you can use custom WSDL file instead of the generated one.
[What is Apache Axis ?](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2002/jw-0125-axis.html)
[Simple tutorial to create Apache axis web service ?](http://www.softwareagility.gr/index.php?q=node/21)
[Calling web service from Android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android)

Comment: thanks Aji, i have big problem which file dependence to create wsdl file like Action or form class

Answer (score 0):

You can use Axis 2 web services.

All you need to know is core java.

Steps:
 1.[Here is a simple tutorial to create a web service](http://www.roseindia.net/webservices/axis2/apache-axis2-hello-world.shtml)

2.After you are done with the server you can test the service using the WSDL(its mentioned in above link as to how to create it(wsdl)) in [**SOAP UI**](http://www.soapui.org/)

3.Now create a simple hello Webservice application in android to consume these services(I prefer ksoap jar to consume services)

Ways to consume web service

```
    1.Ksoap jar

    2. Direct Http call using HttpConnection class.
```

I hope this helps or atleast gets you started...