# what is best approach for consuming Soap based webservices in android

Tags: android

what is best approach for consuming Soap based webservices in android

Answer (score 0):

A web service is any piece of software that makes itself available over the internet that can be remotely invoked using HTTP, that is, it can be activated using HTTP requests. XML is used to encode all communications to a web service. Web services allows you to expose the functionality of your existing code over the network but code are completely invisible to Web site surfers and software users. Their job is to run silently in the background,For example, a client invokes a web service by sending an XML message, then waits for a corresponding XML response. Because all communication is in XML, web services are not tied to any one operating system or programming language--Java can talk with Perl; Windows applications can talk with Unix applications,thus  providing a way for applications to work with each other to get the user the information or functionality he needs.
                Along with XML, Web Services uses standardized industry standard protocol for the communication. All the four layers (Service Transport, XML Messaging, Service Description and Service Discovery layers) uses the well defined protocol in the Web Services protocol stack. This standardization of protocol stack gives the business many advantages like wide range of choices, reduction in the cost due to competition and increase in the quality.

[Read This Tutorial](http://navinsandroidtutorial.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-soap-based-web-services.html)  for entire information.

And read this previous [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-in-android) on same topic.

Comment: I want to know which is best approach to use Soap based services in android. Whether we use third party lib or to use org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.