# Apache Axis2 for Android studio

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app in Android Studio which needs to consume WSDL services written in .net.
Now i need to generate java classes from WSDL file using any third party plugin. I did Google whole day and found  [Apache Axis2 library from here](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/eclipse/plugin-installation.html). But this comes only for eclipse. I have also tried some online tool ex.  [easy WSDL generator](http://easywsdl.com/) but it's all features are available only for premium members.

Now my problem is how can i generate java code using Android Studio. Is there any plugin which can solve my problem. Or any other way...Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Android Studio is for Android development.

Use Eclipse. It works for C, C# and Java.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Apache Axis for this IMHO ...

See if [this](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/accessing-web-service-from-android.html#.VkCgxZTRVC0) helps ...

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-in-android) one ..