# How to consume data via SOAP?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I am responsible to complete an Android app with SOAP. I need to consume data. How do I do that? I am sharing **response**, **request** structure and web url. Thanks in advance.

> url and the others. Just a example is enough for me. What dependencies should I use?

```
URL :  HYPERLINK "http://mobileexam.veripark.com/mobileforeks/service.asmx" http://mobileexam.veripark.com/mobileforeks/service.asmx 

Request :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Encrypt xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <request>RequestIsValid29:01:2015 16:31</request>
    </Encrypt>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Response :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <EncryptResponse 
            xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <EncryptResult>%%UmVxdWVzdElzVmFsaWQyOTowMToyMDE1IDE2OjMx%%</EncryptResult>
        </EncryptResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: search before asking. The `related` section of the question, which is automatically generated and contains simply questions that have the same keywords as yours, contains a few relevant examples. Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-a-soap-web-service-on-android

Comment: "What dependencies bla bla bla... " what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Bro make sure about that I never post any question before searching. I havent found any convenient things so I had to ask that. I might be hired if I complete this app. I need your help. Thanks!

Comment: but you do realize the way you ask the question, there is no indication that you are looking for something that is not already in all the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

@NuhKoca working with SOAP in Android in not something new. Make a small search by using Google and you will find several examples, libraries etc. [Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242) is a library called kSOAP with a nice tutorial. [Here](https://trinitytuts.com/load-data-from-soap-web-service-in-android-application/) is another tutorial for the same library with some additional info regarding the idea behind SOAP. **(5 min. research in total)**

Comment: Thank u so much :)