# Check the username and password using .NET Webservice (SOAP)

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I want to consume a SOAP Webservice in android, created in .NET framework and using it want to check the username and password.

How to check the username and password entered by user with the data which is stored on Server using webservice?

Comment: see this. hope its help you.http://androidexample.com/Dot_Net_Webservice_Call_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=100

Comment: I already worked on that project. Always getting an error - java.net.SocketTimeOutExcepton : Connection timed out @K Neeraj Lal

Answer (score 0):

Use **okHttp** library for android.This library will provide you all the HTTP methods to consume Webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use kSOAP library for it

for more about kSOAP Library check it :

[http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/index.html](http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/index.html/%22kSOAP%22)

and set your webservice class like :

> [How to call a SOAP web service on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-a-soap-web-service-on-android)