# How to get NAMESPACE, SOAP_ACTION, URL and METHOD_NAME to call SOAP request in android

Tags: android, soap, wsdl, android-ksoap2

I have a url for calling in code I should call it with Ksoap2 library in code.

My code is in below,

```
final String NAMESPACE ="";
final String URL ="";
final String METHOD_NAME = "";
final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
request.addProperty(HoldPayment.Amount, "1000");
request.addProperty(HoldPayment.CallbackURL,"http://www.yoursoteaddress.ir/verify.php");
request.addProperty(HoldPayment.Description,"pule kharide tala");
request.addProperty(HoldPayment.Email,"za@gmail.com");
request.addProperty(HoldPayment.MerchantID,"e579752a-a591-11e6-9304-000c295eb8fc");
request.addProperty(HoldPayment.Mobile,"09012345678");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
    Object resultsRequestSOAP = envelope.bodyIn;
    Log.e("","Response::"+resultsRequestSOAP.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error"+e);
}
```

My url is,

```
https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/services/WebGate/wsdl
```

I don't know what I should set to namespace, method, action_soap and url in my code.

Comment: Check this tutorial http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/09/accessing-web-service-from-android.html#.WCLwUmr5jcs

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-a-soap-web-service-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
private static final String NAMESPACE ="http://zarinpal.com/";
private static final String WSDL ="https://www.zarinpal.com/pg/services/WebGate/service";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "PaymentRequest";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = WSDL + "#" + METHOD_NAME;

private static String TAG = "soap";

public static String callWebservice() {
    String responseDump = "";
    try {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty(HoldPayment.Amount, "1000");
        request.addProperty(HoldPayment.CallbackURL,"http://www.yoursoteaddress.ir/verify.php");
        request.addProperty(HoldPayment.Description,"pule kharide tala");
        request.addProperty(HoldPayment.Email,"za@gmail.com");
        request.addProperty(HoldPayment.MerchantID,"e579752a-a591-11e6-9304-000c295eb8fc");
        request.addProperty(HoldPayment.Mobile,"090123456789");

        envelope.bodyOut = request;
        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL);

        transport.debug = true;
        try {
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            String requestDump = transport.requestDump;
            responseDump = transport.responseDump;
            Log.e(TAG, requestDump);
            Log.e(TAG, responseDump);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseDump;
}
```

**This is how I found `NAMESPACE`, `WSDL`, `METHOD_NAME` and `SOAP_ACTION`.**

1. NAMESPACE : Search for "targetNamespace" in the WSDL.
2. WSDL/URL : Search for "soap:address" in the WSDL. The value in location is the URL.
3. METHOD_NAME : I look at the arguments you were using to create the request. It had Amount, CallbackURL, Description, Email, MerchantID and Mobile (no AdditionalData). So I figured you are trying to call `PaymentRequest` method.
4. SOAP_ACTION : Search for "soapAction" in the WSDL. Among the matches, look for the one related to `PaymentRequest`. The SOAP_ACTION is usually the URL + some_seperator + METHOD_NAME. The separator in this case was `#`.

And so I found everything that was required to make the request. Hope it helped you. Good luck.

Comment: @K Neeraj LaI can you tell me how you get NAMESPACE,WSDL ,METHOD_NAME and SOAP_ACTION?